# Laravel Pagination Pretty Urls

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, url-rewriting

Im using laravels default pagination but it prepends ?page=12 onto the url I have changed the url variable from page to ?resource=12 now im trying to figure out how to work this all into creating pretty urls - first stop is obviously nginx but im wondering if anyone out there knows of a native way to do this within laravel and if not can someone help with with the nginx rewrite - so far ive got this which covers the usual laravel serving of pages

```
    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }
```

Comment: Laravel already has pretty URLs. Are you trying to change `?resource=12` into something like `/resource:12`? Or are you asking how to change `page` to `resource`?

Comment: I have it changed to resource but it still shows the url variable rather than just /12/

Comment: See https://www.lukaswhite.com/blog/pretty-pagination-urls-with-laravel-5 for that. (IMO, it's not worth the extra work...)

Comment: I had been using that previously but the plugin is not longer maintained

Comment: The repo says "Feel free to fork our code and maintain your own copy" and I suspect it still works out-of-the-box.

Comment: Yeah its still not a solution. Surely there is a native way to do this within Laravel. This package actually conflicts with another one i use

Comment: There is not, to my knowledge, a native way of doing this in Laravel. It'd be silly to write a package to duplicate built-in functionality, after all.